# recodificación de valores perdidos en R

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy trabajando en R con el comando case_when, generando una variable nueva a partir de una variable originaria. Voy generando los nuevos valores sin problema a partir de los valores de la variable original. Quedan sin embargo un conjunto de casos residuales. ¿Hay algún código que permite asignar un valor a todos esos casos? Es decir, que a "todos los restantes" (los que no entraron en las categorías anteriores), se les asigne una categoría distinta. Me refiero a algo parecido a ELSE en SPSS.
Gracias!

Comment: Si ya estas usando el `case_when()` ya dispones de un "else", simplemente agrega al final agrega un  `TRUE  ~ 'El Resto'`, revisa la documentación: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html